# how does this escaping work?

Tags: shell, makefile, addition

Here is what it finally took to get my code in my makefile to work
Line 5 is the question area

```
BASE=50
INCREMENT=1
FORMATTED_NUMBER=${BASE}+${INCREMENT}

all:
        echo $$((${FORMATTED_NUMBER}))
```

why do i have to add two $ and two (( )) ?

Formatted_Number if i echo it looks like "50+1" . What is the logic that make is following to know that seeing $$(("50+1")) is actually 51?

sorry if this is a basic question i'm new to make and dont fully understand it.

Comment: The GNU make manual is online. The specific reverence to variable references is: http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Reference.html#Reference

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, whenever asking questions please provide a complete example.  You're missing the target and prerequisite here so this is not a valid makefile, and depending on where they are it could mean very different things.  I'm assuming that your makefile is something like this:

```
BASE=50
INCREMENT=1
FORMATTED_NUMBER=${BASE}+${INCREMENT}

all:
        echo $$((${FORMATTED_NUMBER}))
```

Makefiles are interesting in that they're a combination of two different formats.  The main format is makefile format (the first five lines above), but inside a make recipe line (that's the last line above, which is indented with a TAB character) is shell script format.

Make doesn't know anything about math.  It doesn't interpret the `+` in the `FORMATTED_NUMBER` value.  Make variables are all strings.  If you want to do math, you have to do it in the shell, in a shell script, using the shell's math facilities.

In bash and other modern shells, the syntax `$(( ...expression... ))` will perform math.  So in the shell if you type `echo $((50+1))` (go ahead and try it yourself) it will print `51`.

That's why you need the double parentheses `((...))`: because that's what the shell wants and you're writing a shell script.

So why the double `$`?  Because *before* make starts the shell to run your recipe, it first replaces all make variable references with their values.  That's why the shell sees `50+1` here: before make started the shell it expanded `${FORMATTED_NUMBER}` into its value, which is `${BASE}+${INCREMENT}`, then it expanded *those* variables so it ends up with `50+1`.

But what if you actually want to use a `$` in your shell script (as you do here)?  Then you have to tell make to not treat the `$` as introducing a make variable.  You do this by doubling it, so if make sees `$$` then it does *not* think that's a make variable, and sends a single `$` to the shell.

So for the recipe line `echo $$((${FORMATTED_NUMBER}))` make actually invokes a shell script `echo $((50+1))`.

Comment: thats exactly how my file is. sorry i will revise thanks a lot that cleared it up a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this in BASH:

```
FORMATTED_NUMBER=$((BASE+INCREMENT))
```

Is using non BASH use:

```
FORMATTED_NUMBER=`echo "$BASE + $INCREMENT" | bc`
```

Comment: so bash is then doing it?

Comment: also posted non-BASH solution.

Comment: A non-bash solution that's simpler to understand is probably: `expr 50 + 1`